# Sample Controller Component missing for - Unity Tutorial : Motion Tracking with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, sample, tango

"Sample Controller" Component missing for "Unity Tutorial : Motion Tracking with Unity"

1. In Hierarchy, click on Main Camera. (The Inspector tag at the right will show Main Camera at the top.)
2. At the bottom of the Inspector, click the Add Component button. To find the Sample Controller component, start typing the word "Sample" into the search box until it appears.
3. Click on Sample Controller in the menu, and it adds that component.